# ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission is undefined

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have seen this question asked multiple time on SO and went thru their answers thoroughly however, I am still struggling to resolve this problem.

As per multiple answers, I have ensured that maxSdkVersion in android manifest file is 23(I kept minSdkVersion to 15). I also put targetSdk in project.properties to 23. I am running project on android6 and have android-support-v4.jar included from androidsdk/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar.

In android SDK manager, under extras, I have android support repository version 36(which I believe is the latest) and I am using android-sdk-tools 22.6.2

Can anyone please guide why this error still persist? How to remove it?

Comment: The jar provided at `androidsdk/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar` is **not** from the `Android Support Repository` SDK component, but from the obsolete `Android Support Library` SDK component which hasn't been updated for 8+ months. Are you using Gradle?

Comment: Nope I am not. Can you guide from where can I download updated jar

Answer (score 0):

It was issue with obsolete jar from v7 appcompat. I used latest jar for android-support-v4.jar and it worked like a charm!!